# php drop down menu items separated

Tags: php

I am trying to create a drop down menu from an external txt file within my PHP script. I have isolated the proper names using explode(), but not the items are being displayed as 5 separate menus instead of one single menu.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php

 $file_handle = fopen("courselist.txt", "rb");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

$line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
$parts = explode('::', $line_of_text);

echo '<select name="course">';
echo '<option value="'.$parts[0].'">'.$parts[0].'</option>';

echo '</select>';

}

echo'<table>

<form method="post" action="index.php">

            <tr><td>What is your student name?
    <input type="text" name="studentname" /></td></tr>

                <tr><td>What is your student number?
            <input type="text" name="studentnum" /></td></tr>

    <tr><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr>
</form>

    </table>';

fclose($file_handle);

?>
```

course list.txt contains 5 course names with information separated by "::" hence the use of explode() since I only need the name of the course. I am trying to contain all of the course names into a single drop down menu. What am I overlooking?

Thank you!

Comment: try as foreach($parts as $part){
echo '<option value="'.$part.'">'.$part.'</option>'; 
}  your code will display only the first item in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo '<select name="course">';` and `echo '</select>';` should not be in a `while`-loop:

```
echo '<select name="course">';
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
    $parts = explode('::', $line_of_text);
    echo '<option value="'.$parts[0].'">'.$parts[0].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Also, if you want select data to be available via `POST` you should put it into `form`.

Comment: I am familiar with form methods, but in this situation I am confused as to how to implement these options directly into my form?

Comment: You should just echo `<form..>` and after it your select and other fields. And then close form `</form..>`